# Input type="time" and input type="date" don't work flutter webview

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I'm using a flutter webview to fill a form that contains inputs date and time

```
<input type="date">
<input type="time">
```

Those inputs are white wihtout any label (there is no clock or calendar icon, it show with a caret icon like for dropdowns) but I can't click on it.

Any idea ?